# How to validate input data if there are CQRS, DTO and Entity?

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs, clean-architecture

.Net Core 3, Clean Architecture.

I have read a lot articles about data validation with CQRS. For example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091826/should-dto-and-entity-both-have-input-validations) and [there](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/validate-commands-cqrs/).

I have done some conclusions:

1. Need to validate data in DTO. It is contract for entities.
2. Some suggestions from authors validate date into entities (domain).
3. In CQRS AbstractValidator we can validate too, but other rules.

Email field validation will be in 1 and 2.
Age restriction will be in 3.

But three validations in server + one in client are problem (big DRY). 
Where is  better validation in DTO or Entities? I think in DTO, because when I get DTO from input, I can validate and call ModelState.IsValid. But I read some articles that need validate input data in entities too.

So, I'm confused. Can you explain me:

If need to validate an Email field, and an age restriction (18), where need to put validation in Clean Architecture with CQRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your Api contracts, commands should rely on primitive types. Once you want to initialize your domain model, here is where you will not be able to do it, if smth is wrong. If you do DDD, it suggests to prevent object being in invalid state versus validating an invalid object (Domain model vs Crud based).

Comment: I want to do DDD. I should validate DTO (or ViewModel) for user inputs, and validate command objects in domain, aren't I? I can't catch yet.

Comment: No you shouldn't. If your command or dto relies on primitive types(int, string, bool). You would need to create another class (validator) to validate it. That would mean you will duplicate your domain logic. Because only domain knows that Address is valid only when Country is provided, so var address = new Address(country, bla, bla) would fail when you provide null country.

Comment: Sometimes developers pre-validate commands & dtos if data is in there. But not agains your domain rules. So in your commmad you can check if country is null, this is not a valid command, but no more

Answer (score 3):

Clean Architecture splits the responsibility by layers, each layer should have its own validation logic.

Each layer should reject the input which breaks its layer's responsibility. This is validation. So the meaning of validation is differrent depending on its context.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the type of validation. Is it superficial or deep validation?

Superficial validation is things like password strength or checking for the correct format of a URL or email address. Whereas deep validation is the kind of thing that matters to the domain. So that could be something like, is this cargo hazardous or is this person too high a risk to extend credit to.

Check out this post which explains that concept in more detail from a CQRS perspective: [How to validate Commands in a CQRS Application](https://danielwhittaker.me/2016/04/20/how-to-validate-commands-in-a-cqrs-application/)